# How to trigger WPF double-animation from C# code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I want to trigger a double animation from the C# code-behind file. Here is my storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="LiveIconStoryBoard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="TileDoubleAnimation"  
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children) 
        [3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="tileUserControl">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="89"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="89"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.3" Value="-52"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="-52"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

My C# code:

```
Storyboard storyboard;
storyboard = this.TryFindResource("LiveIconStoryBoard") as Storyboard;
if (storyboard != null)
{
    storyboard.Begin(btnStart, true);
}
```

I am getting the following error at the Begin method:

> No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'tileUserControl'.

I suspect it is not finding the target property below:

`(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)`

When I replace this property with some other property, it works fine.

Comment: When i trigger the same animation from XAML it works fine,however when i try to trigger it from C# its throwing exception.

Comment: what is titleUserControl?

Comment: Why do you suspect that WPF is not able to "find the targetproperty" when it *tells you* that it can't resolve the target name?

Comment: @nit titleUserControl is a usercontrol which is used in the main window, the double animation definition is in a resource dictionary which am accessing in the main window.

Comment: @Dwellerincellar try `storyboard.Begin(this, true);`

Comment: @ clemens when i trigger the same animation from XAML it works fine while when i try to trigger from C# file it throws exception, when the target property is changed to some other value then it works fine.

Comment: And what should happen when you start the storyboard on `btnStart`. Does that (Button?) also contain a `tileUserControl`?

Comment: am trying to trigger the animation on button click,@ nit i tried it but it dint work

Comment: @Dwellerincellar did you get the error now?

Comment: @nit yes i got an error stating "'tileUserControl' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'LiveIconsDemo.MainWindow'. where tileUserControl is my usercontrol while LiveIconsDemo.MainWindow is my main window which has this usercontrol added dynamically in a stackpanel in the code behind file

Comment: @Dwellerincellar are you calling begin() before adding user control?

Comment: No its called after adding user control ..

Comment: Use `storyboard.Begin()` overload.